# NullReferenceException thrown on Application.Restart()

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception, application-restart

I have an application that I want to automatically restart after a certain time of the day. I have a timer on the form that ticks every few minutes to see if the time condition is met. If the condition is met, Application.Restart() is passed as an Action delegate to a dialog box. The user is allowed to ignore the message in the dialog if they happen to be in the middle of something important. If the user coplies with the message by pressing ok, the Action delegate is called.

The following exception is thrown:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_UpdatedApplicationFullName()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart()

A few more details: The restart time is midnight. I get the exception in the morning when I click the dialog's ok button. The application is network deployed. I have tested the behavior on two computers so far (both Win 7). Works fine on one, fails on my development machine.

Comment: Well that is interesting. This may be the only documented case for the antithesis of *works on my box*.

Comment: Not enough info here to troubleshoot.  Try running in debug mode so you can get the actual line # the error is occurring on.  Better yet, run it through the debugger and see exactly where it's erroring, and pause execution, inspect all objects onthat line of code and see what's null.

Comment: Could you post us the code within the timer_tick event and the code at click event of the OK button?

Comment: @David and others, note that the exception is in `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment` Used for ClickOnce Deployments, when this happens there is no available data in the application, only external calls `Application.Restart()`, and no arguments